# In the Eternals movie why did no one else notice an epic battle going on?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, eternals-2021

In the Eternals movie it appears as if only the Eternals themselves were aware of the emergence of Tiamut, and they were the only ones to oppose it in the final scenes of the movie.

But during the fighting in London (at the very start of the movie), Ikaris was filmed flying around and shooting beams from his eyes, so it was hard to miss that something weird was going on.  To the point that when they first meet towards the end of the movie, Phastos' son Jack basically asks Ikaris "Are you superman? I saw you on TV!".

So given all this media attention, release of exotic energy weapons, a massive geological disturbance (not to mention an apparently mile high head and fingers emerging from the Earth) and the Domo flying around unimpeded - why did no other superhero or superhero agency at least come and take a look?  EG This sort of thing is totally the purview of S.H.I.E.L.D.

I know from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternals_(film)#Development) that out of universe there seemed to be a desire to not involve other characters:

> Marvel also wanted to create more ensemble films that were not
> crossover films, like Guardians of the Galaxy (2014), while
> introducing relatively unknown characters to audiences as they did
> with that film's title characters and the Avengers.[36]

But in universe it just doesn't make sense to me.  Was everyone else asleep at the wheel, or just tied up with something more important?

Comment: SHIELD no longer exists and at this point neither do the Avengers. Who you gonna call?

Comment: @Paulie_D OK, so technically SHIELD doesn't exist.  But I'd still expect some interest from whatever various superheroes on Earth, or Wakanda.  And this is 5 years after the Blip

Comment: The battle at the end really wasn’t _that_ long and somewhat remote so who was really gonna get there? Also you might as well ask this question of most of the films where only a few heroes are involved.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The battle itself wasn't long, but there was a several day lead up to it, plus strange geological processes going on.  So I would expect people to be asking questions and undertaking surveillance.  The location of the emergence was already effectively being identified on TV even before the battle.  Are you suggesting that the *media* had a better surveillance set up than the people whose job it is to undertake that sort of surveillance?